# string conversions and substrings in Ruby have me baffled

Tags: ruby, type-conversion, substring

I am trying to learn ruby(1.8.7). I have programmed in php for some time and I consider myself proficient in that language. I have a book which I reference, and I have looked at many introductory ruby tutorials, but I cannot figure this out.

```
myFiles = ['/Users/', '/bin/bash', 'Phantom.file']
myFiles.each do |cFile|
  puts "File Name: #{cFile}"
  if File.exists?(cFile)
    puts "#{cFile} is a file"
    cFileStats = File.stat(cFile)
    puts cFileStats.inspect
    cFileMode = cFileStats.mode.to_s()
    puts "cFileMode Class: " + cFileMode.class.to_s()
    puts "length of string: " + cFileMode.length.to_s()
    printf("Mode: %o\n",  cFileMode)
    puts "User: " + cFileMode[3,1]
    puts "Group: " + cFileMode[4,1]
    puts "World: " + cFileMode[5,1]
  else
    puts "Could not find file: #{cFile}"    
  end
  puts
  puts
end
```

produces the following output:

```
File Name: /Users/
/Users/ is a file
#<File::Stat dev=0xe000004, ino=48876, mode=040755, nlink=6, uid=0, gid=80, rdev=0x0, size=204, blksize=4096, blocks=0, atime=Sun Sep 04 12:20:09 -0400 2011, mtime=Thu Sep 01 21:29:08 -0400 2011, ctime=Thu Sep 01 21:29:08 -0400 2011>
cFileMode Class: String
length of string: 5
Mode: 40755
User: 7
Group: 7
World: 


File Name: /bin/bash
/bin/bash is a file
#<File::Stat dev=0xe000004, ino=8672, mode=0100555, nlink=1, uid=0, gid=0, rdev=0x0, size=1371648, blksize=4096, blocks=1272, atime=Sun Sep 04 16:24:09 -0400 2011, mtime=Mon Jul 11 14:05:45 -0400 2011, ctime=Mon Jul 11 14:05:45 -0400 2011>
cFileMode Class: String
length of string: 5
Mode: 100555
User: 3
Group: 3
World: 


File Name: Phantom.file
Could not find file: Phantom.file
```

Wh is the string length different than expected? (Should be 5 for users, 6 for /bin/bash)? Why are the substrings not puling the correct characters. I understand World not being populated when referencing a 5 character string, but the offsets seem off, and in the case of /bin/bash 3 does not even appear in the string.

Thanks

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice one.

When a number is preceeded by a 0, it is represented as octal.  What you are actually getting for bin/bash:

```
0100755 to decimal = 33261
"33261".length = 5
```

And for /Users:

```
040755 to decimal = 16877
"16877".length = 5
```

Add the following line:

```
puts cFileMode
```

And you will see the error.

[to_s takes an argument which is the base](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Fixnum.html#M001076).  If you call to_s(8) then it should work.

```
cFileMode = cFileStats.mode.to_s(8)
```

**EDIT**

```
files = ['/home/', '/bin/bash', 'filetest.rb']
files.each do |file|
  puts "File Name: #{file}"
  if File.exists?(file)
    puts "#{file} is a file"
    file_stats = File.stat(file)
    puts file_stats.inspect
    file_mode = file_stats.mode.to_s(8)
    puts "cFileMode Class: #{file_mode.class}"
    p file_mode
    puts "length of string: #{file_mode.length}"
    printf("Mode: #{file_mode}")
    puts "User: #{file_mode[-3,1]}"
    puts "Group: #{file_mode[-2,1]}"
    puts "World: #{file_mode[-1,1]}"
  else
    puts "Could not find file: #{file}"    
  end
  puts
  puts
end
```

Comment: So what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish is to inspect and possibly alter the last 3 digits of that octal number. Specifically, I want to check the second to last digit and add 2 to it and chmod the file if it does not contain one (check using bitwise &). Am I making this harder than it needs to be? Can you show me how or point me to a resource that demonstrates something like this?

Comment: ok that last edit should get me there - Thanks! I'll check out in my code and accept your answer when it works

Comment: I am still not getting the expected result after add the cFileMode = cFileStats.mode.to_s(8)

Comment: Let me guess, the values are correct on files, not on folders?  You should access to permissions from the end as the length is variable.  See my edits.  I also converted the variables from camelCase to underscores and use interpolation instead of concatenation on the strings.

Comment: WOW - Thanks! and the iterations have helped my understanding greatly

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
puts "length of string: " + cFileMode.length.to_s()
```

What you want is this:

```
puts "length of string: #{cFile.length}"
```

Please do not use **camel case** for variables in Ruby, camel case is used on **class names only**, method and variable names should be written with underscores to separate multiple words.

It's also a good practice to avoid adding parameters to method calls that **do not have parameters**, so, instead of calling **to_s()** you should use **to_s** only.